# 2-step estimation of DCC GARCH model in Python

Tags: volatility, time-series, garch, estimation

Embedded in this thread are multiple questions.  I'm currently im the process of implementing a DCC GARCH forecast model on quantopian (a python-powered trading platform).

The two step consists of first estimating the conditional volatility over time $D_t$ (as canonicalized by Engle).  I apply the traditional log-likelihood with the minimize function from scipy package.  For 2nd step, it is the same except I run into a bit of ambiguity:

Consider the log-likelihood for the 2nd step $L(\phi|\hat{\theta})\propto \sum_{t=1}^{T}log(|R_{t}|)+\epsilon_t^{'}R_t^{-1}\epsilon_t$.  The first term evaluates to an N by N matrix while the second term evaluates to a scalar.  Thus, the likelihood for each timestep is an N by N matrix.  In implementation, only a scalar is expected to be return, do I just sum all the terms in $log(|R_t|)$ when calculating the actual likelihood?

Furthermore, the current time it takes for the minimize function to converge takes too long, any advice on faster estimation techniques is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If $\log{(|R_t|)}$ is your first term, I'm not sure why this is a matrix. Modulus (determinant herein) applied to a matrix $R_t$ gives a scalar. If your implementation in python produces a matrix, that's likely because modulus is treated as an element-wise abs() function for each element of a matrix.

It may be easier and faster to use `rugarch` (univariate GARCH) and `rmgarch` (multivariate GARCH) packages in R to fit DCC model parameters. You can access these from within Python. These packages allow an easy speed up with clustered processing. Alternatively, there is a `ccgarch` package in R allowing DCC fitting.

Calling R from Python is numerously discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716923/python-interface-for-r-programming-language), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213517/how-to-call-ltm-function-using-rpy-package-in-python), and in many other posts.

[Unstarched website](http://unstarched.net/r-examples/rmgarch/) has many helpful DCC GARCH examples.

Comment: This is a really old post but thank you very much for taking your time still to answer it.  I realized that it was the determinant function after I posted this thread.  However, I find your links on implementing R in python to be really interesting so I'll look more into that field regardless :)

Comment: You are welcome. Hopefully, this will help others implement DCC as well.